# How can we find this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty \\x\to\infty}f^n(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ and $a,b,c,d>0$ then  $f^1(x)=f(x), f^2(x)=f(f(x)), f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))$ and $f^n(x)={f(f(f\cdots f(x)\cdots )))}$, where $ f^n(x)$ is the $ n $ composition of the function $f(x).$

> It's required finding this limit:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty \\x\to\infty}f^n(x)$$

It is possible to find $f^n(x)$ for finite number $n$. For example, I found $f^2(x) = \frac{a^2 x + a b + b c x + b d}{a c x + b c + c d x + d^2}$. I can't do more than that. What is the math level of this problem? In fact, I wanted to solve. But I could not.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps the matrix formulation helps. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations

Answer (score 6):

One approach is using linear algebra: For a matrix $ M = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix}$, put  $f_M(x)=\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{\gamma x+\delta}$. Then direct computation shows that
$f_M(f_N) = f_{MN}$. 
In your case, $f = f_A$, and $f^n=f_{A^n}$, with $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. From this follows the answers to your question in the text is:
1. The level of math is linear algebra (where you learn how to compute powers of matrices, e.g., by eigenvalues or jordan form) and calculus 1 (where you learn to compute the resulting limit).
And the answer to the question in the title is: Yes with some work.

Comment: (+1) Is it possible to add more details to your answer?..

Comment: @Elementary what kind of details? On the composition? On powers if matrices?

Comment: Can you look 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101388/548054

Comment: Your say that , is answer equal to $1$? This is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the limits by recursion. If $p_n = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f^n(x)$, then

$$ p_{n+1}=\frac{a \cdot p_n+b}{c\cdot p_n+d}$$
And $p_0=a/c$

There should exist some results on this kind of sequences.