# Where is the mistake in my approach?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

I did a little research for the question [I asked before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101080/548054)

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ and $a,b,c,d>0$ then  $f^1(x)=f(x), f^2(x)=f(f(x)), f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))$ and $f^n(x)={f(f(f\cdots f(x)\cdots )))}$, where $ f^n(x)$ is the $ n $ composition of the function $f(x).$
>
> It's required finding this limit:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty \\x\to\infty}f^n(x)$$

The source I use is [here:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function)

\begin{align}
f^n (x) &=\frac{a}{c} + \frac{bc - ad}{c} \left [ \frac{(cx - a + \alpha)\alpha^{n - 1} - (cx - a + \beta)\beta^{n - 1}}{(cx - a + \alpha)\alpha^{n} - (cx - a + \beta)\beta^{n}} \right ] \\
\alpha &= \frac{a + d + \sqrt{(a - d)^2 + 4bc}}{2} \\
\beta &= \frac{a + d - \sqrt{(a - d)^2 + 4bc}}{2}
\end{align}

And here is my approach:

> $f^n (x)=\frac{a}{c} + \frac{bc - ad}{c} \left [ \frac{(cx - a + \alpha)\alpha^{n - 1} - (cx - a + \beta)\beta^{n - 1}}{(cx - a + \alpha)\alpha^{n} - (cx - a + \beta)\beta^{n}} \right ]\Rightarrow f^n (x)=\frac{a}{c} + \frac{bc - ad}{c} \left [ \frac{(cx - a + \alpha) - \left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{n-1} (cx - a + \beta)}{(\alpha cx - \alpha a + \alpha^2) - (\beta cx - a \beta + \beta^2)\left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{n-1}}
>  \right ]=\frac{c-\left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{n-1}
> c+\frac{\alpha-a}{x}}{\alpha c-\left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{n-1}
> \beta-\frac{\alpha a-\alpha^2}{x}}×\frac{bc-ad}{c}+ \frac{a}{c}$
>
> It is obvious if $a,b,c,d>0$, we have $\alpha>\beta.$ Let, $n\to \infty$, we have
>
> $$f^n(x)=\frac{c+\frac{\alpha-a}{x}}{\alpha c-\frac{\alpha a-\alpha^2}{x}}×\frac{bc-ad}{c}+ \frac{a}{c}.$$
>
> Then, for $x\to\infty$, we have
>
> $$f^n (x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}×\frac{bc-ad}{c}+ \frac{a}{c}.$$
>
> So, I found
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty \\x\to\infty}f^n(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}×\frac{bc-ad}{c}+ \frac{a}{c}.$$

But, In the question [I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101080/548054), I was told that the answer was $ 1 $. What did I do wrong? Can you explain?

Thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function

Comment: Is the limit taken $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\infty}[...]$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}[...]$? Or do you have a proof that the order doesn't matter?